# MySQL Joins and ORDER BY in PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks like this with two tables

```
Items
id          |       Title
-----------------------------
1                   Bus
2                   Plane
3                   Jet
4                   Shoes
5                   Chair
```

```
Sorting
id               |         CatID         |       ItemID          |  SortOrder
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1                            3                      3                   3                 
2                            3                      2                   1
3                            3                      4                   2
4                            3                      1                   0
5                            4                      5                   4
```

I can't figure out how to list the Titles of the **ITEMS** table based on the "SortOrder" Column of the **SORTING** table.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Sorting ON Items.id = Sorting.ItemID 
    WHERE Sorting.CatID = 3 
 ORDER BY Sorting.SortOrder
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

**EDIT**

It looks like the MySQL query is correct, the problem is happening because when I output the $row['id'] of the Items Table it is incorrect.  I have an Ajax PHP update that is updating the database based on the id of an li tag.

Any ideas why the $row['id'] is outputting incorrectly? I think it has something to do with the **Items.id = Sorting.ItemID**

Comment: you can also specify  DESC or ASC

Comment: your query looks just fine, what the output vs. expected output ?

Comment: Agreed; it looks okay; do you want to change the sorting *order*?

Comment: what is happening when you are trying above mentioned query?

Comment: The order just seems to be random I can't figure out why

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bf97/1 Seems fine.

Comment: Just figured out that it isn't necessarily a problem with the query, For some reason when I output the id from the Items Table (e.g. $row['id']) it outputs the wrong ID which is throwing off the Ajax query I have which is updating the Sort Order Table.  So I guess I need to figure out why the $row['id'] is wrong, I think it has something to do with setting the Items.id = Sorting.ItemID

Comment: So looks like I need to output it $row['ItemID'] because $row['id'] is defaulting to the id of the Sorting table which was throwing off the sort method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as expected - [SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41f00/1):

```
SELECT i.*, s.SortOrder
FROM items i, sorting s
WHERE i.id = s.ItemID 
  AND s.CatID = 3 
ORDER BY s.SortOrder
```

Comment: See the edit above, discovered it's not a problem with the query, but the $row['id'] is being outputted incorrectly.  This query works like the original.  Not sure which one is better or faster though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
     FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Sorting ON Items.id = Sorting.ItemID 
    WHERE Sorting.CatID = 3 
 ORDER BY Sorting.SortOrder ASC
```

add `DESC` or `ASC` in `ORDER BY` clause.

if you use `ASC` then sorted result will be `0 1 2 3 4` for `SortOrder`.

**sample php code to get title**

```
<?php
    $query  = mysqli_query(above_query)or die(mysqli_error());
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
           echo $result['title']. '<br/>';
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. Perfectly acceptable answer.